# What will be the SQL statements issued to cause these grants to exist in the dictionary and for each what user has executed it?

Tags: sql, oracle

When executed:

```
SELECT grantee,owner,table_name,grantor, privilege, grantable
    FROM user_tabs_privs;

|**Grantee |    Owner|  Table_Name| Grantor |Privilege| Grantable**|
|----------|---------|------------|---------|---------|------------|
|MEGAN     |EMILY    |SALES       | ADAM    |SELECT   |NO          |
|----------|---------|------------|---------|---------|------------|    
|JO        |EMILY    |EMP         | EMILY   |DELETE   |NO          |
|----------|---------|------------|---------|---------|------------|    
|ADAM      |EMILY    |SALES       | EMILY   |SELECT   |YES         |
|----------|---------|------------|---------|---------|------------|
```

Comment: The SQL statement used to create the grants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a row of the table you can retrieve the statement:

as user `grantor` issue

```
GRANT privilege ON owner.table_name TO grantee;
```

if `grantable` is "no".

```
GRANT privilege ON owner.table_name TO grantee WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

if `grantable` is "yes".

But one does  not know then a statement was issued.

A user can grant a privilege on an object owner.table_name if he is the owner of the object- Also a user can grant a privilege on an object if the privilege was granted to him with grant option.

From this the following is a possible sequence of statements.

```
--as user Emily
GRANT select ON emily.sales TO adam WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT delete ON emily.sales TO jo;

-- as user adam
GRANT select ON emily.sales TO megan;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for these table grants is straightforward:

```
GRANT privilege ON table TO user (WITH GRANT OPTION)
```

So for example, for the bottom record, Emily granted Adam the SELECT privilege on the Sales table, `WITH GRANT OPTION` (so he could grant it to someone else, as he did in the first record):

```
GRANT SELECT ON Sales TO Adam WITH GRANT OPTION
```